# Use of ProposalIndex in pallet-collective

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template, pallet-collective

What is the use of **ProposalIndex** in pallet-collective? However, we also have **proposal_hash** for identifying the proposal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have gone back in time to find out the reason for `ProposalIndex` :D

[Here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/694#discussion_r216271657) you find the comment that lead to this addition. Personally I'm not really convinced that this proposal index is required. Even if someone sends again a proposal with the same hash, it would be the same proposal (assuming there is no hash collision).